# I want to install textblob

Tags: python-3.x

code:

```
import textblob            
from textblob import TextBlob
incorrect=input('enter')
correct=TextBlob(incorrect).correct()
print(correct)
```

error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Python/spell
> checker.py", line 1, in 
> import textblob ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textblob'

Plzz help me! I have installed textblob and in Command Prompt it is showing :

> Requirement already satisfied: textblob in c:\python\lib\site-packages
> (0.15.3) Requirement already satisfied: nltk>=3.1 in
> c:\python\lib\site-packages (from textblob) (3.6.2) Requirement
> already satisfied: regex in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from
> nltk>=3.1->textblob) (2021.4.4) Requirement already satisfied: joblib
> in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from nltk>=3.1->textblob) (1.0.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: click in c:\python\lib\site-packages
> (from nltk>=3.1->textblob) (8.0.0) Requirement already satisfied: tqdm
> in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from nltk>=3.1->textblob) (4.61.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\python\lib\site-packages
> (from click->nltk>=3.1->textblob) (0.4.4)

plzz help

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code you change the interpreter here (at the bottom left corner of the screen) enter image description here

[image]

Ready! Now your Python interpreter should find the module.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the package according to your python-version,for python3 use this

```
!pip3 install textblob
```

If you did not receive an answer,the installation of the package not completed. You should install the package properly.

```
pip install -U textblob
python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

or
TextBlob is actively developed on  [github_source](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob)

You can clone the public repo:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob.git
```

Once you have the source, you can install it into your site-packages with

```
$ python setup.py install
```